# Get Average of a field between two dates in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, Table A has a date field for every day of the year and a rate field for each of those days. Table B has a list of certain dates. How do I get the average of the rate field in Table A for the first date in Table B and the second date in Table B, then the average rate in Table A for the second date and the third date in Table B and so on and so forth.

Below is my attempt thus far.

```
Select Tran_Date, avg(rate)
From [dbo].[10_Year_TBill_Rates] a
left join #cashwithrn b
on a.observation_date = b.Tran_Date
where Tran_Date is null
group by Tran_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the row: where Tran_Date IS NULL:

```
SELECT Tran_Date, ISNULL(AVG(rate), 0)
FROM [dbo].[10_Year_TBill_Rates] a
LEFT JOIN #cashwithrn b
ON a.observation_date = b.Tran_Date
GROUP BY Tran_date
```

Comment: Hi, I actually need the average between two dates not the average on that date.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only average two numbers at any time, it might be easier to do something like this:

```
; With CTE as (Select b.date
    , a.rate
    , row_number() over (order by b.date) as RN 
from TableB b
left join TableA a
on b.date = a.date)

Select a.date as Date1
    , b.date as Date2
    , (a.rate + b.rate)/2 as AverageRate from CTE a
left join CTE b
on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
```

Note that the `row_number` is unnecessary if you already have sequentially assigned IDs in your table.

The first part retrieves the rate for each of the dates in B, the second part connects that rate with the rate from the row immediately following it, and averages them.

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you might be able to simplify this with `lag` or `lead`.  If you are uncomfortable with CTEs, you can apply the same logic using a temp table instead.